# JSONObject inside JSONArray

Tags: java, arrays, json

I'm trying to put a JSONObject inside a JSONArray in Java. Here is my two objects:

JSONArray:

```
[{
    "url": null,
    "flag": "0",
    "read": "0",
    "time": 2000,
    "exp": null,
    "population": 10
}]
```

JSONObject:

```
{
"events": [
    {
        "color": "Green",
        "event": "Restart"
    },
    {
        "color": "Black",
        "event": "Shutdown"
    },
    {
        "color": "White",
        "event": "Read"
    }       
]
}
```

Expected result:

```
[
{
    "url": null,
    "flag": "0",
    "read": "0",
    "time": 2000,
    "exp": null,
    "population": 10,
    "events": [
        {
            "color": "Green",
            "event": "Restart"
        },
        {
            "color": "Black",
            "event": "Shutdown"
        },
        {
            "color": "White",
            "event": "Read"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

I tried to use this code, but the result is not ok:

```
jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
```

Unexpected result:

```
[
{
    "url": null,
    "flag": "0",
    "read": "0",
    "time": 2000,
    "exp": null,
    "population": 10
},
{
    "events": [
        {
            "color": "Green",
            "event": "Restart"
        },
        {
            "color": "Black",
            "event": "Shutdown"
        },
        {
            "color": "White",
            "event": "Read"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

The "events" key-value most be inside the unique element in JSONArray, not as another element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `JSONArray` contains one `JSONObject`. When you `jsonArray.put(jsonObject);`
 you are adding it to the `JSONArray`, not to the `JSONObject` in the `JSONArray`.

This will add the `jsonObject` to the first `JSONObject` in your `JSONArray`

```
jsonArray.getJsonObject(0).put("events",jsonObject.get("events"));
```

Comment: That's exactly what I expected.

Answer (score 2):

You need,

```
((JSONObject) jsonArray.get(0)).put("events", jsonObject.get("events"));
```

Or, in a more generalized form,

```
    for (Map.Entry entry : (Set<Map.Entry>) jsonObject.entrySet()) {
        ((JSONObject) jsonArray.get(0)).put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not tested the code but I think this would work. Try it if you want.
`jsonArray[0].events` will create a new field named 'events' in the 0 indexed Object.

```
 jsonArray[0].events = jsonObject.events;
```